# How to change textColor on press Even in Android?

Tags: android, layout

Is it possible to change the text color of a textview if the textview is pressed?
I want to achieve a flashing effect with the color change only lasting as long as the button is pressed.

I know how to change the background of the textview with a selector list and the correct state but how can I change the color of text if the user pushes a button or a simple textview?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a selector for colors as well. A short example that only distinguishes between pressed and all other states is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:color="#FFFFFF" />
   <item
      android:color="#4C566C" />
</selector>
```

For a full documentation on the selector see this [unofficial documentation](http://idunnolol.com/android/drawables.html#selector).

Put every color selector in a single file and put this files in a directory called color in the resources folder of your project.

Comment: this only works for text color. If you want to use it for a background color you need to define a color drawable in each item.

Comment: for newbies like me, an additional info, set the textColor property to this drawable in order to set the effect.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html):

XML file saved at res/color/button_text.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:color="#ffff0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
<item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

This layout XML will apply the color list to a View:

```
<Button
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/button_text"
android:textColor="@color/button_text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change it using the [setTextColor(ColorStateList)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor%28android.content.res.ColorStateList%29) method

```
myTextView.setTextColor(myColorStates);
```

Answer (score 1):

search for color selector to use in the

> android:setTexColor

attr

Comment: What is android:setTexColor an attribute of?

Answer (score 0):

```
myTextView.setTextColor( 0xFFFF0000 )
```

Comment: this won't have the desired effect I want to get a flashing change while the user presses and change the color back at the moment he releases the textview

Comment: i'd suggest adding that requirement to your original question